# How to configure each location point to a seprate upstream in nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, load-balancing, rewrite

How to configure each location point to a separate upstream in nginx?

I need functionality like this.

www.mysite.com --> 127.0.0.1:9900 or upstream.

www.mysite.com/serviceA --> 127.0.0.1:9901

www.mysite.com/serviceB --> 127.0.0.1:9902

and so on.

I tired this,

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9900;
        }
        location /serviceA/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9901;
        }
        location /serviceB/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9902;
        }
    }
```

and this also

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9900;
    }
    location /serviceA/ {
        rewrite ^/serviceA/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9901;
    }
    location /serviceA/ {
        rewrite ^/serviceB/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9902;
    }
}
```

It also not working. any suggestion for me?

But the / is working , others are not working

Comment: Other than the spelling of `serivce`. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @RichardSmith sorry that was a typo while asking question here. now I changed it .

Comment: @RichardSmith, the error I am seeing , It not serving the content for me. :(

Not Found

The requested URL /serviceA/ was not found on this server.

Comment: And I am seeing every where it was used like this only. but for me it not woking. 

https://www.garron.me/en/linux/nginx-reverse-proxy.html

Comment: maybe must to reorder location block.put location / in below other